# Why (and in favor of what) are maven-bundle-plugin's wrap/bundleall goals deprecated?

Tags: maven, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/releases/maven-bundle-plugin-2.3.7/doc/site/wrap-mojo.html says `bundle:wrap` is deprecated, same with `bundle:bundleall`. I currently use `wrap` to create an OSGi bundle from a non-OSGi dependency, as described at http://www.lucamasini.net/Home/osgi-with-felix/creating-osgi-bundles-of-your-maven-dependencies. What should they be replaced by and what's the reason for the deprecation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The alternative is to just use the bundle:bundle goal, then in your pom.xml configure the plugin similar to the following:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <instructions>
         <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
         <_exportcontents>*</_exportcontents>
      </instructions>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

You can control what dependencies get embeded and exported by changing the wildcards "*", scope, etc. attributes.

Comment: This doesn't work for me without `<extensions>true</extensions>`

Answer (score 4):

I've wondered the same question, found some clue here:

http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@felix.apache.org/msg22221.html

"Instead new features/goals will be added to solve common use-cases such as 
creating mega-bundles, etc."

I guess they're going to rework the current goals because the current codebase doesn't support all that they want to implement in the plugin.