# Maven dependency using xml file

Tags: java, maven-3

I have add a dependency in pom.xml, like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
  <artifactId>features-restconf</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1-Lithium-SR1</version>
  <classifier>features</classifier>
  <type>xml</type>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This dependency is an xml file, it is something like: (for simplicity)

```
<feature name ='odl-mdsal-apidocs' version='1.2.1-Lithium-SR1' description="OpenDaylight :: MDSAL :: APIDOCS">
        <feature version='1.2.1-Lithium-SR1'>odl-restconf</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:org.opendaylight.controller/sal-rest-docgen/1.2.1-Lithium-SR1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.3.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.3.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.3.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-json-org/2.3.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.3.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.3.2</bundle>
</feature>
```

I found that all dependencies as described as < bundle > in xml file will be downloaded into local repository. So I think it is another way to do with project dependency. But I can not find any information about this usage of dependency in pom.xml.

Where can I find materials about this part of Maven? Is there any document or tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the bundle functionality has been depreciated.  That's probably why you can't find much information on it.  Another post shows the information about it being deprecated along with an alternative way of doing bundles. See the link below.

[Why (and in favor of what) are maven-bundle-plugin's wrap/bundleall goals deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103666/why-and-in-favor-of-what-are-maven-bundle-plugins-wrap-bundleall-goals-deprec)

Hope this helps